# Robocopy switches to replace GoodSync for steam game library

Tags: batch-file, steam, robocopy

I'm currently using GoodSync to sync my Steam folder to other computers on the network. I have steam scheduled to auto run in the morning, and after game updates it closes and Goodsync runs after that.

I am looking to use Robocopy as a replacement and/or have a batch file for each pc so I can do one at a time if ever needed.

Here is the problem I have;
GoodSync takes about 7 minutes per computer. 
Robocopy takes about 25 minutes per computer with the /mir switch
I have both set to run 20 threads.

I'm not sure how GoodSync is comparing files as it's all in GUI form. And why it's so much faster.

I'm wondering how I can speed this up, and what switches I can use to help. I think there is a way to only copy new files from last "2" days but what if something happens and it dosent run for 4-5 days? I don't want to cause problems with the steam folder on the other computers on the network.

Any suggestions will be helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Would the /XO switch be good enough for this kind of task?

Comment: :-/ Anyone on here...